# Getting Syntax error on joining two tables

Tags: sql, syntax

```
(SELECT user_id, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) AS month, EXTRACT(DAY FROM created_at) AS day 
FROM marketing_automation_mail_logs
GROUP BY user_id, month, day) q1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT user_id, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) AS month, EXTRACT(DAY FROM created_at) AS day 
FROM referral_link_share_intents
GROUP BY user_id, month, day) q2
ON q1.user_id = q2.user_id
WHERE q1.month = q2.month AND q1.day = q2.day
```

I am using this query to join two tables but it shows me the syntax error near INNER JOIN. I don’t understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: You need a `SELECT * FROM` first.

Comment: Why do you put some join conditions in the WHERE clause instead of in the ON clause?

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
select * from (
SELECT user_id, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) as month, EXTRACT(DAY from created_at) as day from marketing_automation_mail_logs
group by user_id, month, day) q1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT user_id, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_at) as month, EXTRACT(DAY from created_at) as day FROM referral_link_share_intents
GROUP BY user_id, month, day) q2
ON q1.user_id = q2.user_id
WHERE q1.month = q2.month AND q1.day = q2.day
```